# Locking files. What to do first? Unlock or close?

Tags: c, linux, locking, cgi-bin

I do unlock and then close.
One process appends records ABCDEFGHIJ.
Another process reads the same file and writes ZZZZ.
Normal file  should be
ZZZZ
ABCDEFGHIJ

But only once I have seen the following:
ZZZZEFGHIJ
So the record ABCDEFGHIJ is damaged with ZZZZ.

It seems my locking does not work.
But I tested it. One process really waiting for another.
Can another process write to the file between open and lock?
Or between unlock and close?

The code is below

```
int MyOpenWrite(char *name,int flags) {
int fd
fd = open(name,flags,S_IREAD|S_IWRITE|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
LockFile(fd);
return fd;
 }

int WriteFile(char *name, char *data) {
...
fd = MyOpenWrite(fullName,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
write(fd,data,strlen(data));
UnLockFile(fd);
close(fd);
}

int ReadFile(char *name, char *data, int maxLength) {
fd = open(name,O_RDONLY);
LockFile(fd);
...
UnLockFile(fd);
close(fd);
}

int AppendFile(char *name, char *data) {
fd = MyOpenWrite(fullName,O_WRONLY|O_APPEND);
...
len=write(fd,data,strlen(data));
UnLockFile(fd);
close(fd);
 }

int LockFile(int fd) {
struct flock    lock;
lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
lock.l_start = 0;
lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
lock.l_len = 0;
return fcntl(fd,F_SETLKW,&lock);
}

int UnLockFile(int fd)  {
struct flock    lock;
lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
lock.l_start = 0;
lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
lock.l_len = 0;
return fcntl(fd,F_SETLKW,&lock);
}
```

I tried close(fd) the UnLock(fd).
It seems it works.
But there is a delay between open and lock anyway.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should flush the file before unlocking it?

Comment: Hmm. I doubt.Flush just writes to HDD. I think if file is not written to HDD and second process reads it, it should read it from cash, not from HDD.

Comment: No, `fflush`-ing a file actually writes the file.

Comment: `fflush` flushes stdio buffers.  It doesn't guarantee that the bits are physically written to disk by the kernel.  You need `fsync` for that.

Comment: You have no guarantee that Process A and B share a cache for file I/O.

Comment: he is using write, not the buffered fwrite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't `write(2)` to a file (after the unlocking), it does not matter if you unlock it first or `close(2)` it first.

However, `close(2)`-ing a file would unlock it (at least if no other process share the same opened file descriptor).

See [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) which says

> ```
> As well as being removed by an explicit F_UNLCK, record locks are
> automatically released when the process terminates or if it closes any
> file descriptor referring to a file on which locks are held.
> ```

#### addenda: should check for failures

Notice that your code is missing error checking. Almost every library function or syscall, in particular `fcntl`, `read`, `write`, could fail (and set `errno` to be displayed by e.g. `perror` or `strerror(errno)` in some log or print). You don't check the success or failure of `fcntl` in your `LockFile` or `UnlockFile` functions, and you don't check neither in the caller.

Comment: I understand. But what is wrong in my lock, if it does not work?

Comment: You should check for failures, as I just added.